# Display Static Block in phtml

Tags: magento, checkout, block

i want to show an static block directly in Template. I know that I can do this in this way:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(6)->toHtml();
```

That calls to the Static Block with the id 6. But this Block needs the Parameter product_id="product/1".

What I need:

```
<block type="test/test" product_id="product/1" block_id="8"/>
```

I want to set the Product Id in Template. It is possible to set the product id directly in the Template?

Such as

```
<block type="test/test" product_id="product/$currentProductId" block_id="8"/>
```

(For your Information. That Snippet should be placed at checkout/cart)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Blocks have the so-called "magic getters and setters" via `Varien_Object::__call()`. You can therefore set your parameter by

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                      ->setBlockId(6)
                      ->setProductId('product/1')
                      ->toHtml();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that didn't work in my case. I think i have to try a another way :)